# Product attribute join with custom table Magento 2.17 - how to retrieve custom table field

Tags: product-attribute, magento-2.1.7, zend-framework

In my code I have `seller_id` as the product attribute and the seller information are there in a custom table **(lof_marketplace_seller)**. I want to join the product collection with this custom table. I did the join this way:

```
$collection = $productCollection->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->load();
 $collection->getSelect()->join(

                ['lof_marketplace_seller'],
               'lof_marketplace_seller.seller_id = e.seller_id',
                []


        )->columns(['seller_name'=> 'lof_marketplace_seller.name']);
```

and then I write this to get the seller name:

```
foreach ($collection as $value) {
    $sellerName = $value->getData('seller_name');
    ................
}
```

But I'm not able to get seller name by using the code. When I try to generate the SQL from the $collection, I'm able to get the fields & values exactly. (by `$collection->printlogquery(true)`)

My question is how to retrieve the `seller_name` from the result set.
OR **simply how to retrieve custom table field in a JOIN operation**

$productCollection Variable:

```
class Json extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {
    private $productCollection;
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    \ESPL\Autocomplete\Helper\Data $helper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollection,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $store,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $image,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $product
)
{
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->helper = $helper;
    $this->productCollection = $productCollection;

}

public function execute()
{ 

   $productCollection = $this->productCollection;
   $collection = $productCollection->create()
   ............................
```

Thanks,

Comment: print `$collection` object and see, you are getting `seller_name` or not

Comment: When I print_r($collection), it outputs a long object array. Actually we can get the name, entity_id etc from $value->getData() function. But seller_name is not getting. Also it is not throwing any error

Comment: That means your joining query is incorrect.

Comment: No I'm able to generate the SQL using $collection->printlogquery(true) and able to run the SQL in my phpmyadmin. It shows output

Comment: Can you please update your code about `$productCollection` variable?

Comment: Can you please  tell  me, what is attribute type of  `seller_id `

Comment: @AmitBera, the seller_id is a custom attribute added to the product. Actually it holds the seller_id. lof_marketplace_seller is the master table for sellers (it is a Marketplace plugin table from Land of coders)

Comment: `seller_id ` is save at  magento show eav table product table like catalog_product_entity,catalog_product_entity_varchar,catalog_product_entity_int etc  or your customer table?

Comment: @AmitBera, seller_id is saved on product related table. I think it is loaded from there. it is foreign key to lof_marketplace_seller table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer!. Thanks to Land of coders 
https://landofcoder.ticksy.com/ticket/1307647

this is the answer:

```
foreach ($collection->getData() as $value) {    
   $sellerName = 
 $value['seller_name'];    ................
```

}

Can anybody suggest **me links or tutorial which give the good documentation for customizing magento especially what are its inner functions and how to use them for common customization purposes**. It is very hard to customize magento.